# PowerShell Can I convert my object string into actual object?

Tags: powershell

Can I convert object represented as string into a real object?

```
$test = ConvertFrom-String "@{LOCAL='hello'}"
$test
```

Something like the preceding?

Comment: What kind of object are you expecting? What you have there can be easily converted to a hashtable using the parser

Comment: A hash table would work, how do I do that from that string

Comment: [Found it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables?view=powershell-7.3#convertfrom-stringdata), thanks Santiago

Comment: `ConvertFrom-StringData` is for key values delimited by `=` how is that the same as you're showing in your question? It would require trimming of `@{` and `}`. Why not give the right information in the question to begin with?

Comment: `$test = Invoke-Expression "@{LOCAL='hello'}"` but [Take reasonable precautions when using the Invoke-Expression cmdlet in scripts. When using Invoke-Expression to run a command that the user enters, verify that the command is safe to run before running it. In general, it is best to design your script with predefined input options, rather than allowing freeform input.](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression#description)

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I wasn't sure what ways there were to convert string into object, sorry about that. I should have said I wasn't locked into that design.

Answer (score 2):

For the string you're showing in question using the [`Parser` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.language.parser?view=powershellsdk-7.3.0), it is quite simple:

```bash
& ([System.Management.Automation.Language.Parser]::ParseInput(
    "@{LOCAL='hello'}", [ref] $null, [ref] $null)).GetScriptBlock()
```

This works because `hello` is quoted, if however you have multiple hash tables embedded in a string and they may or may not be quoted, then it would require a bit more work:

```bash
$string = "@{LOCAL='hello'}; @{foo=bar}"

$ast = [System.Management.Automation.Language.Parser]::ParseInput($string, [ref] $null, [ref] $null).
    FindAll({ $args[0] -is [System.Management.Automation.Language.HashtableAst] }, $true)

foreach($hashAst in $ast) {
    try {
        $hashAst.SafeGetValue()
    }
    catch {
        foreach($pair in $hashAst.KeyValuePairs) {
            @{ $pair.Item1.SafeGetValue() = $pair.Item2.Extent.Text }
        }
    }
}
```